# Issue with Inserting integer and string into SQL Server database c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I am having trouble inserting the integer value [Question Type] and the string [Question Space] into my database at the same time into the same row. Whenever I click the button and try to execute an error comes up saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Code:

```
SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ([Question Space], [Question Type]) Questions VALUES ('@QuestionText', '@checkedradiobutton')", connect);
command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionText", QuestionText);
command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkedradiobutton", checkedradiobutton);

command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I would appreciate any help that anyone can give me.

Here's the whole code for the button if you want to see:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connect.Open();

    int checkedradiobutton = 0;
        
    if(radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        checkedradiobutton = 1;
    }
    else if(radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        checkedradiobutton = 2;
    }
    else if(radioButton3.Checked)
    {
        checkedradiobutton = 3;
    }

    string QuestionText = QuestionBox.Text;

    SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ([Question Space], [Question Type]) Questions VALUES ('@QuestionText', '@checkedradiobutton')", connect);
    command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionText", QuestionText);
    command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkedradiobutton", checkedradiobutton);

    command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] 
(
     [QuestionID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [Actual answer]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
     [Question Space] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
     [Question Type]  INT           NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionID] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax for INSERT INTO is

```
INSERT INTO <table> (field1, field2, fieldN) VALUES (value1, value2, valueN)
```

so your command should be written as

```
SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Questions  
                        ([Question Space], [Question Type]) VALUES  
                        (@QuestionText, @checkedradiobutton)", connect);
```

Note how the parameters placeholders should not be enclosed in single quotes because doing that you tranform them in literal text. (Inserts the `"@QuestionText"` string in your `[Question Space]` field)

Finally, try to avoid AddWithValue, it is a shortcut with numerous drawbacks as you can read in [Can we stop using AddWithValue already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and in [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

This is still a single line of code

```
 command5.Parameters.Add("@QuestionText", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = QuestionText;
```

Comment: @mot375: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wrap parameters with ' inside the query. Start cleaning it and see if it works

```
    SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Questions] ([Question Space], [Question Type]) Questions VALUES (@QuestionText, @checkedradiobutton)", connect);
    command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionText", QuestionText);
    command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkedradiobutton", checkedradiobutton);


    command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT syntax is wrong, the name of the table should go after "INSERT INTO", e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Cheers.